# syslog-ng "log_msg_size" maximum possible value

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I read from syslog-ng doc and forums that  log_msg_size to defaults to 8192.
What is the possible maximum limit of this parameter?

My application supports either syslog-ng or rsyslog depending upon situation and need.
I wanted to set "log_msg_size" to 64KB (that is what the support given by rsyslog). Is it ok and will it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That limit is by default, if yours is a 32 bit system your limit will be 4GByte, if is 64bit the limit is unlimited but you have to consider the capability of your Filesystem (Ext3,4,bitrfs...).My suggestion is never make big ASCII file, for scaling up it's much better to use mysql or postgres exp with syslog-ng.

Answer (score 1):

it might depend on the version of syslog-ng, but if it is not too old, 64k should work AFAIK. If it does not, file a bug report at https://github.com/balabit/syslog-ng

Robert